# Prove that $(-2)^n$ is divergent using the definition only

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Prove (by definition only) that $(-2)^n$ is divergent.
First, I recall the definition:

First of all let's assume that this sequence is not divergent - there exists an unique number $g$ such that 
$$(\forall{\epsilon >0)}{(\exists n_o \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\ge n_o)(|a_n-g| < \epsilon)} $$

And so we should be able to find the value of n based on the value of $\epsilon$. However, this sequence behaves different with even and odd arguments, thus I'd like to separate this and consider two cases: 
1) $n = 2k, k\in \mathbb{N} $
$$|(-2)^{2k}-g| < \epsilon$$
$$|2^{2k}-g| < \epsilon$$
$$-\epsilon < 2^{2k}-g<\epsilon$$
$$-\epsilon +g < 2^{2k} < \epsilon+g$$
2) $n = 2k+1$ Following the seme scheme, I get to 
$$-\epsilon-g <2^{2k+1}<\epsilon-g$$
$$\frac{-\epsilon-g}{2} < 2^{2k}< \frac{\epsilon-g}{2}$$
Is it enough to call it a proof?

Comment: You can't call it a proof because you didn't write down the contradiction you get.

Comment: But is the argumentation I've used on the right track?

Comment: For a *proof* you should actually say what the relation between each of those lines is. If you want to write a proof down, you usually read this as implications (i.e. line 1 $\implies$ line 2 e.t.c). Furthermore you should first introduce all the variables before you're using them. Also what is the conclusion each time?

Comment: It might be easier to negate the statement: For all $g$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for for all $n_0$ there exists $n\ge n_0$ such that $|a_n-g|\ge \epsilon$. Though, it comes to much the same thing as you are trying to do.

Comment: @Aemilius You are almost there. If $(-2)^n$ converges then the inequalities must hold for all $\epsilon,k$. Is it possible? For example $\epsilon=1$ and $k=100000$?

Comment: @EclipseSun, These two inequalities don't hold for all possible values but I don't have an idea how I can write it down. Perhaps I could show that the product of these two sets for even and odd n-s is empty, but I don't know if I can do this using variables only.

Comment: You can simply assume it holds for $\epsilon=1,k=100000$. Then derive some absurd inequalities like $0>1$ and finish the proof by saying you get an contradiction.

Comment: Eclipse Sun, 
Is it considered a "formal" proof to assume certain values of variables? I mean, is it technically correct? Also, if I wanted to use such values, do I have to consider two cases, for even and odd numbers? I guess one would be enough and easier to prove a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

A sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb R$ is divergent, if and only if
$$\forall g \in \mathbb R \: \exists \epsilon > 0\:\forall n_0 \in \mathbb N\: \exists n >n_o : |x_n -g| \ge \epsilon.$$
Now consider the case of $x_n = (-2)^n$. We will show divergence by strict application of the definition. Let $g \in \mathbb R$ be given. We claim $\epsilon = 1$ will suffice. Let $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ be given. We claim $$n \ge \max \{n_0, \log_2(1 + |g|)\}$$ will suffice. Why? Because the triangle inequality implies
$$ |x_n - g| \ge ||x_n|-|g|| \ge |x_n| - |g| = 2^n - |g| \ge (1 + |g|) - |g| = 1 = \epsilon,$$
and by construction $n \ge n_0$. This completes the proof.

Note: Depending on the intended audience, I would stress that the functions $x \rightarrow 2^x$ and $x \rightarrow \log_2(x)$ are monotone increasing on their natural domains, as this fact was quietly used.

Comment: Notice Carl's proof uses a great deal of explanatory language as opposed to bare mathematical statements. This style can be a little more time consuming to write, but it is a thousand times clearer to the reader (and often the writer, as well).

Comment: @AustinMohr Thank you for your kind words which made my day.